# Twitter Bootstrap doesn`t show icons in firefox

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap

Good day!!! When I develop site I used twitter bootstrap css framework. I create buttons with bootstrap icons but Firefox does not display its.

Help me please solve the problem!

Comment: Could you add the HTML snippet you are using to display the icons?

Comment: Can you see the icons on this page in your version of Firefox? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons

Comment: Show the code and I am sure someone can help you on it.

Comment: Please show the code.

Answer (score 0):

Without a code sample, it's hard to know what the real issue is, but I can provide some examples of buttons with icons using Bootstrap that work in Firefox (and other browsers).

A sample delete button (using a link with "btn" class):

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">
   <i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete
</a>
```

A sample delete button (using "button" element):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
  <i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete
</button>
```

For more information:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not allow cross domain fonts. you will need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for your font files. check out [this link](http://www.red-team-design.com/firefox-doesnt-allow-cross-domain-fonts-by-default) for more details. if you're using rails you can use [this gem](https://github.com/rubymaverick/font_assets)